# iPhone4 app does not load from "Recently Used App" list, just get blank black screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, background, multitasking

I am running into a very odd issue.  I have an app that works perfectly, compiles with no errors, and when launch from springboard loads perfectly.  It will load from springboard every time correctly, even if it is running in the background.  However, sometime if I launch the app from the recently used app list, by hitting the home button twice, the app wont load.  It just displays a blank black screen. applicationWillEnterForeground: and applicationDidBecomeActive: are not called when launching from the recently used app list.  This only happens occasionally, most of the time the app will launch from the recently used list.  Anyone else out there seeing anything like this.

Thanks in advance,
Jason

Comment: Sounds buggy.. you may want to file a Radar with Apple about this.

Answer (score 0):

You might be doing heavy operations when applications calls this method

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application ;
```

remove heavy operations from this method